# Getting Posts from Facebook page with specified fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I developed asp.net web form that takes posts from facebook pages using my facebook application by this code

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    string oauthUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}", "appid", "appsecret");

    string accessToken = client.DownloadString(oauthUrl).Split('=')[1];

    string pageInfo = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/Mypage?access_token={0} ", accessToken));
    string pagePosts = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/Mypage/posts?access_token={0} ", accessToken));
```

this code returns **`all posts with their all fields`** 
but I need to **`choose some fields of them not all`**
How can I do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should really familirize yourself with Facebook .Net API: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/making-synchronous-requests/

if you use it, here is a code to get certain fields from Post objects and images associated with the post (if any):

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var query = string.Format(@"{{ 
""posts"":""SELECT post_id, actor_id, attachment, permalink, app_data, type, likes.count,comments.count,message,source_id ,updated_time,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = {0} and updated_time > {1} and type > 0 LIMIT 100"", 
""photo_posts"":""SELECT photo_id, src, width, height FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id in (SELECT attachment.media.photo.fbid FROM #posts where type=247) and width > 300 and width < 500 order by width desc""}}",  userId, LongExtensions.DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(expirationDate.DateTime));

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.q = query;

IList<dynamic> postsRaw = ObjectExtensions.ToData(this.client.Get("fql", parameters));
```

you can remove image part if you don't need it.

Comment: notice, **fql** is deprecated: _(OAuthException - #12) (#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher_